# Multiclass logistic regression - implementation question

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, logistic-regression

This is my try to implement multi-class logistic regression in python using softmax as activation function and mnist digit data set as training and test set.

```
import numpy as np

def softmax(z):
   return np.array([(np.exp(el)/np.sum(np.exp(el))) for el in z])

def cost(W,F,L):
   m = F.shape[0] #get number of rows
   mul = np.dot(F, W)
   sm_mul_T = softmax(mul)
   return -(1/m) * np.sum(L * np.log(sm_mul_T))

def gradient(W,F,L):
   m = F.shape[0]  # get number of rows
   mul = np.dot(F, W)
   sm_mul_T = softmax(mul)
   return -(1 / m) * np.dot(F.T , (L - sm_mul_T))

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("./datasets/MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

W = np.zeros((785, 10)) #784 features + 1 bias

for _ in range(10000):
   F, L = mnist.train.next_batch(100)

   F = np.insert(F,0, values=1, axis=1)

   total_cost = cost(W,F,L)
   print("Total cost is {}".format(total_cost))

   gradients = gradient(W,F,L)

   W = W - (0.1 * gradients)

FU = mnist.test.images

FU = np.insert(FU,0, values=1, axis=1)

LU = mnist.test.labels

mulU = np.dot(FU, W)
sm_mulU = softmax(mulU)

OK=0
NOK=0

for i in range(10000):
   a1 = np.argmax(sm_mulU[i])
   a2 = np.argmax(LU[i])
   if a1 == a2:
      OK = OK + 1
   else:
      NOK = NOK + 1

print("{} OK vs {} NOK".format(OK, NOK))
print("accur {}%".format((OK/(NOK+OK))*100))
```

What I wanted to do is basically to try to implement it myself and try to get similar results as using Tensor flow. But the problem is that tensor flow implementation gets in the end 91% accuracy, while I can get only around 70%. Also, it seems like my model diverges and cost starts to increase pretty fast.

Is my implementation wrong, or is it due to more advanced algorithm inside TensorFlow implementation?

Comment: first initialize your weights to small random numbers that may help, second you can add a bias term, third , usually logistic regression is done in a one-vs-rest manner for more than 2 classes, maybe tensorflow uses that, you can try it. you can also add regularization term and try better optimizers than plain gradient descent.

Comment: @leo I added bias parameter, but seems like nothing changed that much. I'm not sure if my gradient function is OK?

Comment: I guess so, the formula is correct and you are getting 70% accuracy which is way more than random guessing (10% for 10 class in your case), so it's correct. but do the rest of options I mentioned too, see what happens. you use simple mini-batch gradient descent, implement a more powerful algorithm like **Adam** optimizer ,it's very popular in deep learning, or use momentum in gradinet. formulas are similar search it. I think that alone would  give your model a major boost. and it's better to use np.random.rand() or something similar instead of zero initialization of your Weight matrix.

Comment: I find a good way of checking what you need to do. this is scikit-learn SGDclassifier, see what kind of parameters and option it uses and what are the default value, and implement them. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html
one more thing I noticed is that you only train for 1 epoch, why is that? you should usually go several times through your whole dataset, I mean to have 2 for loop, one for epochs(how many times to train the whole dataset) and another one for your batches to get them and train them chunk by chunk.

Comment: OK, instead `np.sum(np.exp(z)))` I should have done`np.sum(np.exp(el)))` since z is whole matrix, and I need just row of all the features.

Comment: It works now with accur 92.36999999999999%

Comment: yes that's correct, I did not notice that :p